# How to use InStr function in VBA 2003?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below returned error 5 at InStr call:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
     Dim wb As Workbook
     Dim wbs As Workbooks
     Dim str As String
     Dim LPosition As Integer

     Set wbs = Application.Workbooks
     For Each wb In wbs
        str = wb.Name
        LPosition = InStr(0, str, "_", vbTextCompare)
        MsgBox LPosition
     Next wb
End Sub
```

Could someone please explain why?

Comment: It give error 5 at Instr call. Can't resolve the question? Please Help Me

Answer (score 5):

Start index of `InStr` function is 1-based => 0 is invalid value.

See *Exceptions* section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, and one could have found out by reading the function-definition in MSDN... :( +1 for you -1 for OP